# Circular reference handling

Tags: javascript, circular-reference

Given that modern Javascript engines can better detect circular references, is the code below acceptable? If not, what would be the design pattern in Javascript to mitigate this?

```
class Validator {
    constructor(elem) {
        this._elem = elem;
    }

    validate() {
        if (this._elem.value < 0) {
            throw new Error('Value cannot be negative');
        } else {
            console.log('Value is valid');
        }
    }
}

class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this._validator = new Validator(this);
        this._value = 0;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(newVal) {
        this._value = newVal;
    }

    validate() {
        this._validator.validate();
    }
}
```

and this has

```
p._validator._elem === p
```

Would passing in interfaces like the below code mitigate this

```
class Validator {
    constructor(valueGetter) {
        this._valueGetter = valueGetter;
    }

    validate() {
        if (this._valueGetter() < 0) {
            throw new Error('Value cannot be negative');
        } else {
            console.log('Value is valid');
        }
    }
}

class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this._validator = new Validator(()=> {return this.value});
        this._value = 0;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(newVal) {
        this._value = newVal;
    }

    validate() {
        this._validator.validate();
    }
}
```

However, this too seems to mask the reference wrapped because the function passed into the `Validator` class has the reference to the `Parent` class.

Comment: Circular references are not a problem for mark-and-sweep garbage collectors.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's what my reading indicated but nevertheless, is this acceptable? I have a lot of C++ baggage (to unlearn while coding in JS :)) and this wouldn't be correct in that world but is this paradigm commonly used in JS or are there better ways to handle this than assuming proper garbage collector algorithms?

Comment: The code is fine, what problem are you having with it?.   Circular references are fine in JS, it's circular modules that can cause issues.   The only time circular references have been a problem, was when Microsoft IE tried using reference counting instead of a GC..  But that was years & years ago, something like IE6..

Comment: @Keith I'm not having an issue with this code per se but this is a toy example and I wanted to be certain that this doesn't have any issues during garbage collection or design-wise. So the answer to my question `...Is this acceptable?`, the answer seems to be yes. Thank you all for the responses. Please do post an answer with more nuances and references, if possible so that I can logically close this question.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  lets assume P for Parent & C for child.   And you have   P->C &  C->P  if nothing references either P or C, it will get GC'ed.  The only time in JS you can get a kind of memory leak is if something on the global keeps hold of say P or C, eg.  if you did this -> `setInterval(() => console.log(this))` in your parent constructor, then  P will never GC and as such C will neither.

Comment: No modern language has any general problems with circular references. The only place where you will run into a problem is if you try to serialize the objects (e.g. convert the objects to JSON), since most serialization formats don't have a way to represent internal references.

Comment: @Barmar I hope you'd count C++ as a _modern_ language :) where circular references are an issue. Here's an [example](https://onlinegdb.com/eB4WEg8gw) )where the class instance is never destroyed. Again, as I'd mentioned earlier, I don't want to baggage myself with C++ while coding JS. My query was purely around whether the code is acceptable and as you and others have mentioned, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Zoso I assumed the context was just languages with automatic garbage collection, so C++ is not relevant.